# How to Webscraping Instagram Profile link BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, instagram, instagram-api

I'm just starting to learn how to web scrape using BeautifulSoup and want to write a simple program that will get the profile links (instagram url) of my idol via FullName in Instagram.

Example: I have FullName list stored in file fullname.txt as follow:

```
#cat fullname.txt
Cristiano Ronaldo
David Beckham
Michael Jackson
```

My result desire is:

```
https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/
https://www.instagram.com/davidbeckham/
https://www.instagram.com/michaeljackson/
```

Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: There are plenty of existing python questions similar to this. This is not a specific question, please refine your question to ask something more specific than just how to code a thing, you may find better help that way. https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/ProblemSolving/doc1.n-S-3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for all 3 names, and a few others I added to fullname.txt

It uses the Requests library and a Bing search to find the correct link, then uses regular expressions to parse the link out of the returned packet.

```
import requests, re

def bingsearch(searchfor):

    link = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q={}&ia=web'.format(searchfor)

    ua = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36'}

    payload = {'q': searchfor}

    response = requests.get(link, headers=ua, params=payload)               

    try:
        found = re.search('Search Results(.+?)</a>', response.text).group(1)

        iglink = re.search('a href="(.+?)"', found).group(1)

    except AttributeError:
        iglink = "link not found"

    return iglink


with open("fullname.txt", "r") as f:
    names = f.readlines()

for name in names:
    name = name.strip().replace(" ", "+")

    searchterm = name + "+instagram"

    IGLink = bingsearch(searchterm)

    print(IGLink)
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But when I run then get result "link not found" :(
I try read your code. But I don't know to fix it.

Comment: Weird, it's working on my computer. Since I can't see what your computer is finding in the packet sent back from Bing: in the code above, put "print(response)" before the line that says "try:". Then look at the output of the program in your terminal. Run a search in your terminal (top menu), search for "www.instagram.com/michaeljackson" or whichever name it searched for first. If it's found, then you can parse the output differently to get the correct link.

Comment: I put print(response) before the line "try". This is my results http://prntscr.com/meu7a2 . Can u help me?

Comment: Oops, I meant "print(response.text)". There will be a large output this time.